# Compare three file and print the highest value

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have three files. All of them having only one column.

```
File1 
M
0
M
A

File2 
A
0
M
A

File3
M
0
A
A
```

compare each row in the three files, i.e, for first row (M,A,M)
hence the maximum occurrence is M. The in the output file should contain M in the first row. likewise for other rows in the three files

```
Output file
M
0
M
A
```

can anybody tell the awk script for this....

Comment: is it homework?

Answer (score 3):

Try something like:

```
awk '$1"">A[FNR]{A[FNR]=$1} END{for(i=1; i<=FNR; i++)print A[i]}' file*
```

`$1""` is used to force $1 into string context, so that a string comparison is performed..

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk

```
paste  file{1..3} | awk '{n=split($0, a, "\t");
           asort(a,b,"@val_str_desc"); print b[1]}'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
paste file[123] |
while read -a values; do printf "%s\n" "${values[@]}" | sort | tail -1; done
```

Comment: In hindsight, I'm not keen on this solution: the external `sort` will be invoked once per line, so the performance will be slower than the awk solutions.